# How to remove the endpoint of format=json using Servicestack v3

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

I have built my restful service using `Servicestack`.

For example my host url is `userinfo/update?format=json`.

Now  I want to remove the endpoint `?format=json`, but still return response in JSON format. Client requires JSONformat only.

My solution is:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
{
    EnableFeatures = Feature.Json
});
```

But after that I cannot visit the metadata url `/metadata`

How to deal with it?

Comment: Are you asking "How do i make the HTTP request to /userinfo/update with a JSON response, with using format=json parameter?"

Comment: yes I want to control through Server cod ,Is these soma methods?

Answer (score 2):

If your client requires JSON format responses, configure your client to send the HTTP Accept: header to the service.

```
Accept: application/json
```

Your servicestack service [will read the Accept: request header](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Formats#rest-endpoint) and know to serialize the response to JSON, without needing the ?format=json parameter.

Comment: I want to control through  Server cod ,Is these soma methods?